# possible clashes of tcolorbox with enumerate package and the totpages package

Tags: enumerate, page-breaking, tcolorbox

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, UTF8, scheme = plain, twoside]{ctexart}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[top=0.5cm,left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,bottom=2.28cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pdfsuppressptexinfo=-1

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{totpages}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse,breakable}
\tcbset{%
    colback      = white,
    tikz         = {opacity=0.8,transparency group},
    colframe     = black,
    title filled = false,
    colbacktitle = white,
    breakable,
    enhanced
}%%
\NewTColorBox[
    ]{question}{ O{}mo }{
    fonttitle                 = \bfseries,
    coltitle                  =  black,
    title                     = #2,
%   after title               = {\hfill Page~\thepage~of~10000},
    after title               = {Page~\thepage\ of~\pageref{TotPages}},
    before lower              = {\textbf{Solution\quad}},
    #1
}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand*{\mytopic}[2]{%
\clearpage
    \begin{question}{Exercise \path{#1} }
        \includegraphics[scale=1.18]{example-image-a.pdf}
        \tcblower
        #2
    \end{question}
}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%  DOC Begins   %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%do compile%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\mytopic{Q1_490}{
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
\lipsum[4]
\[
    \lambda = 2\times10^5
    \qquad
    l_0 = 2
\]
\lipsum[5-8]
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\mytopic{test_223}{
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
\lipsum[20]
%% \begin{enumerate}
%% \item $mv = 50\times 10 = 500 $ Ns
%% \item $mv = 5\times10^3\times4 = 20,000$ Ns
%% \item $mv = 7000\times10^3\times40 = 2.8\times10^8$ Ns
%% \item $mv = 2\times10^{-16}\times10^{-3}\times1\times\times10^{-3} = 2 \times 10^{-22}$ Ns
%% \end{enumerate}
\lipsum[25-28]
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

This MWE cost me 8 hours over two days just to location where the possible problems might be .........so exhausting.....

**Problem 1** - possible clash with the `totpages` package.
We can't seem to use

```
    after title               = {Page~\thepage\ of~\pageref{TotPages}},
```

It does not compile and gives a `fatal error`.

**Problem 2** - possible clash with the `enumerate` package.
The `enumerate` environment can't be used. If so, same error

```
! pdfTeX error (ext4): link annotations cannot be inside an XForm.
<argument> ...shipout:D \box_use:N \l_shipout_box 
                                                  \__shipout_drop_firstpage_...
l.75 }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has to do with the `transparency group`. When you use that tcolorbox/tikz will put the box in a xform object and links are not allowed in such an object.

A simple example to get your error (at the second compilation) is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcbset{tikz={transparency group},enhanced}

\begin{document}
\section{abc}\label{sec}

\begin{tcolorbox}
hello \ref{sec}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Your options here are either to remove the `transparency group` or to avoid any active links inside the tcolorbox, e.g. by using `\pageref*` and `\ref*`, or -- probably safer -- by surrounding the box with a `NoHyper` environment.

Comment: OMG!!!! Never occur to me that would be a problem during the 8 hours of bugging and trying to location what the problem really is ........ THANKS!!! Seemed to be working perfectly now, even in the actual project!